# How do I join a $wpdb query with user meta using default value if not exist?

Tags: mysql, wpdb, user-meta, performance, date-time

I am implementing a new feature to a website which gives users a certain amount of credits every week, if they are of a certain membership level.

We are using *Paid Memberships Pro* and *MyCred*. Both are great plugins that are working wonderfullly.

I have a routine that fetches all users at a certain level, then check user meta for the last date where points were awareded. This function is run daily as wrapped in a cron action.

The query to fetch users which is wrapped in a function called `dt_get_pmro_users_at_level` and is correctly prepared :

```
SELECT user_id, startdate
FROM wp_pmpro_memberships_users
WHERE membership_id
IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM wp_pmpro_membership_levels
  WHERE name = 'Premium'
)
AND status = 'active'

???? INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ?????
```

**How do I join the query above with the user meta check for `last_awarded_points_date`, using `startdate` as a default value (if not exist) ?**

The catch: It needs to be backwards compatible. I need to assume that some users will not have a `last_awarded_points_date` meta.

Im sure its a walk in a park for SQL wizards. Which I am definitely not.

At the moment I pull all users from the database, make another DB call to pull usermeta, convert dates from MySQL to unix timestamps and check them individually ... which is *sloooooow*.

For context, this is the whole routine :

```
function dt_membership_credit_cron( $level_name, $credits ) {

  // fetches all users
  // using the query above
  $users = dt_get_pmpro_users_at_level( $level_name );

  // get current time
  $time_now = current_time( 'timestamp' );

  // for each user...
  foreach ( $users as $user ) {

    // each $user is a stdClass with
    //   user_id      Int
    //   startdate    MySQL formated timestamp

    // get last time
    $last_time = get_user_meta( $user->user_id, 'dt_last_awarded_points_date', true);

    // If no last time
    if ( empty( $last_time ) ) {
      $last_time = $user->startdate;
    }

    // get differece between last time and now
    $diff = $time_now - strtotime( $last_time);

    // if difference is smaller than a week in seconds
    // its not time ... yet. Skip
    if ( $diff < 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 ) { continue; }

    // otherwise...

    // grant credits
    mycred_add( 'credit', $user->user_id, $credits, 'Credit' );

    // update new date
    update_user_meta( $user->user_id, 'dt_last_awarded_points_date', date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $time_now) );

  }

}
```

Any help is greatly apreciated. I am very open to suggestions on how to improve this code!

Cheers!